# How to print the count of occurrence of a categories for a give feature?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

My dataframe looks as above. I want to group the data by using Hour2 column and show the count for each Light_condition category in front of it. But not able to figure how is to be done.
I want something like:

> Night- time |category-name| category count

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['Hour2', 'Light_Conditions'])['Light_Conditions'].count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.crosstab` and depending on the format you need, unstack followed by resetting the index:

```
np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Light_Conditions':np.random.choice(["Daylight","Darkness"],10),
                   'Hours2':np.random.choice(['Daylight','Night-time'],10)})

  Light_Conditions      Hours2
0         Daylight    Daylight
1         Daylight  Night-time
2         Daylight  Night-time
3         Daylight  Night-time
4         Daylight    Daylight
5         Darkness    Daylight
6         Darkness  Night-time
7         Daylight    Daylight
8         Daylight    Daylight
9         Daylight    Daylight

pd.crosstab(df['Hours2'],df['Light_Conditions'])
Light_Conditions  Darkness  Daylight
Hours2                              
Daylight                 1         5
Night-time               1         3

pd.crosstab(df['Hours2'],df['Light_Conditions']).stack()
Hours2      Light_Conditions
Daylight    Darkness            1
            Daylight            5
Night-time  Darkness            1
            Daylight            3

pd.crosstab(df['Hours2'],df['Light_Conditions']).stack().reset_index()
 
       Hours2 Light_Conditions  0
0    Daylight         Darkness  1
1    Daylight         Daylight  5
2  Night-time         Darkness  1
3  Night-time         Daylight  3
```